encrypting a single partition
Im trying to encrypt a single 2TB drive, i want to have 1tb for windows 11 and 1tb for ubuntu, but i want both drives encrypted, ubuntu with luks and windows with bitlocker, the windows side of things is easy but ubuntu is not, as most luks installations ask to format the whole drive rather than the single partition

does this Linux for Devices article answer your question?
